# Is communication by JMS between JBoss 5.x and JBoss 6.x possible?

Tags: jboss, jms, compatibility

Is communication by JMS between JBoss 5.x and JBoss 6.x possible?

Or do you need same version on both sides because of class version compatibility reasons?

Comment: I'm not sure, but unless JBoss 6.x JMS implementation is compatible with JBoss 5.x, OSGi might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss 5 and 6 use different JMS implementations (JBoss Messaging and HornetQ, respectively), so I suspect that they're not interoperable. However, since HornetQ is based on the Jboss Messaging codebase, it's possible that the HornetQ broker in JBoss 6 can be made interopable, but it's not going to be easy.

I suggest trawling the HornetQ documentation to see if it's even possible.